# How do I create ssh_authorized_key resources in a puppet provider? (do I force a flush?)

Tags: puppet

Full code is at https://gist.github.com/c9815c1b19a36ed07ca5

In `nodes.pp` I have

```
node 'random.brighterplanet.com' {
  $deploy_user = 'www-data'
  include secured_by_authorized_keys
  include logs_in_as_deploy
}
```

In `modules/logs_in_as_deploy/manifests/logs_in_as_deploy.pp` I have

```
class logs_in_as_deploy {
  access_via_authorized_key { $deploy_user:
    ensure => present
  }
}
```

In `modules/secured_by_authorized_keys/lib/puppet/provider/authorized_keys.rb` I have

```
# [...]
def to_ssh_authorized_key(name, ensure_status)
  k = Puppet::Type.type(:ssh_authorized_key).new :name => id(name), :ensure => ensure_status, :key => public_key, :type => 'ssh-rsa', :user => name
  k.provider.create
  k
end
# [...]
Puppet::Type.type(:access_via_authorized_key).provide(:authorized_keys) do
# [...]
  def create
    ks = AuthorizedParty.all.map do |authorized_party|
      authorized_party.to_ssh_authorized_key resource[:name], :present
    end
  end
# [...]
```

I see

```
# puppet --debug  /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp 
[...]
notice: /Stage[main]/Logs_in_as_deploy/Access_via_authorized_key[www-data]/ensure: created
debug: Finishing transaction -611364608
debug: Storing state
debug: Stored state in 0.01 seconds
notice: Finished catalog run in 2221.41 seconds
```

But nothing is written to the `authorized_keys` file. I think I either have to

- add the built-in `ssh_authorized_key` resource to the node catalog somehow
- call flush on it somehow

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I commented on your gist.

I believe this custom type code is quite a bit too optimistic about employing the native ssh_authorized_key type. Hardcoding resources into the type code and ignoring the catalog contents is borderline abusive.

It would be prudent to implement this in a manifest instead

```
$keys = { 'rimuhosting' => { 'id' => ... }, ... }

define my_authorized_key($ensure = present) {
  $data = $keys[$title]
  $key_name = $data['email'] + "-" + $data['public_key_version'] + "-" + $data['user']
  ssh_authorized_key {
    "$key_name":
      ensure => $ensure,
      type => 'ssh-rsa',
      ...
  }
}
```

And since all-or-nothing seems to be the goal

```
class authorized_keys($ensure = present) {
  $names = keys($keys)   # <- function from puppetlabs-stdlib module
  my_authorized_key { $names: ensure => $ensure }
}
```

Parameterized classes can be fugly to use, if you want to go this route, I highly recommend to combine it with [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup).